# Instance members of singleton object or static members of class

Tags: c#, java, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I am writing a listener class which creates a single HttpListener on random 
unused port and listens on it. I tried to make it singleton. However I am 
finding it difficult to keep that singleton object `null` when listening 
to random HTTP port fails 10 times.

(I have shown port number and HttpListener instance as members of singleton 
instance. However there are many other members that I have not shown for 
simplicity.) This is my code:

```
class Listener
{
    private static Listener listener = null;  //singleton instance

    //member variables
    private HttpListener httpListener = null;
    private int port = -1;

    static Listener()
    {
        listener = new Listener();
    } 

    private Listener()
    {
        try
        {
            port = //randomly generate
            httpListener = new HttpListener();
            //start listening
        }   
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //cant listen on randomly chosen port
            listener = null;
        httpListener = null;
            port = -1;
            return;            
        }   
    }
}
```

However inside `catch()`, `listener = null` sets `listener` to null 
just for a while. When default constructor returns it returns a new
instance of `Listener`, thus `listener` inside static constructor always have 
instance assigned to it. Thus instead of `listener = null` inside default 
constructor it should be `this = null` which is invalid.

Thus I moved the whole code inside static constructor. But that forcesd me to

- Either make instance members (`port` and `httpListener`) `static`  or
- or use `listener.port` , `listener.httpListener` everywhere

  class Listener
  {
      private static Listener listener = null;  //singleton instance

  ```
  //member variables
  private HttpListener httpListener = null;
  private int port = -1;

  static Listener()
  {
      listener = new Listener();

  try
      {
      listener.port = //randomly generate
          listener.httpListener = new HttpListener();
          //start listening
      }   
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          //cant listen on randomly chosen port
      listener = null;       
          return;            
      } 
  } 

  private Listener()
  {  
  }
  ```

  }

I dont understand

**Q1** whether to make `port` & `httpListener` `static`?  (This I feel somewhat against OOP principles) or

**Q2** whether to keep them as instance members and use `listener.` everywhere? (This is problematic since there are many such members and methods in my actual code and I have to attach `listener.` everywhere)

Or I am thinking it all wrong and should have followed different approach?

Comment: Are you trying to hack a port?

Comment: [why singletons are evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx). It really doesn't seem in the context you're describing that you need a singleton.

Comment: @BartoszKP ohkay... whats exactly wrong here?

Comment: This is really weird, what are you trying to accomplish? Try to [avoid the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why are you setting listener to null? It's a static member, and as a singleton it should not be nulled unless you recreate it later, which is strange because other consumer classes could potentially save a reference to the old member.

Comment: Am I not clear in explanation? My Listener class creates `HttpListener`, makes it listen on a randomly chosen port, and then attached it a callback method. Since there will always be one listener I made `Listener` singleton.... Is this still unclear?

Comment: You could have a "Init" or "Start" method which creates the httpListener and starts listening instead of doing it in the constructor. Then you won't have to recreate listener.

Comment: @Patrick I have to register the URI on which the listener is listening to some web service. The registration code first checks if it is null, if it is, it throws exception, otherwise it registers the URI so that it will receive notifications from that webservice.

Comment: @Patrick that `init` , `start` sounds good can u write pseudo code?

Comment: @Patrick But again I think those `init` and `start` needs to be `static` only?

Comment: @Mahesha999 What's wrong is forcing the usage of singleton here. What your really have here is an abstract factory pattern, not singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BartoszKP mentions in the comments, you would probably be better of with a factory pattern here.

If you are interested in having a common place for events you *could* place that event in the factory class, or implement a static event in the Listener class.

```
public class ListenerFactory {

    public IListener CreateListener(URI uri, int port) {
        Listener l = new Listener();
        l.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
        // do whatever with l. loop until connection, or use l.Start() for instance
        return l;
    }

    public static event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> ListenerMessageReceived;

    private static void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e) {
        // trigger ListenerMessageReceived
    }
}

public interface IListener {
    event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> MessageReceived;
    void Send(byte[] data);
}

public class Listener : IListener {
    // implement interface
}
```

Then you just call `new ListenerFactory().Create(host, port);` when you need a new Listener, and if you want to listen for all messages, you subscribe to `ListenerFactory.MessageReceived` for incoming messages.

Using this pattern, you can create several connections at once instead of relying on one class to handle all of them.

---

You should move the initialization code of httpListener to its own method in order to avoid recreating listener. By doing that, and adding a property for getting the listener instance, classes can use `Listener.Instance.Start()` to reconnect if the static constructor fails to connect.

```
public class Listener
{
    private static Listener listener = null;  //singleton instance

    //member variables
    private HttpListener httpListener = null;
    private int port = -1;

    static Listener()
    {
        listener = new Listener();
        // start listener
        try {
             listener.Start();
         }
         catch { }
    }

    // Use this method in other classes to start listener if it fails
    // in static constructor
    public static Listener Instance { get { return listener; } }

    private Listener()
    {
    }

     public bool IsConnected {
         get { return httpListener != null; }
     }

     public void Start() 
     {
        if (IsConnected) { return; }
        try
        {
            port = //randomly generate
            httpListener = new HttpListener();
            //start listening
        }   
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //cant listen on randomly chosen port
        httpListener = null;
            port = -1;
            return;            
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: hey u set `httpListener` to `null`. Shouldnt I be setting `listener` to `null`. Or its just that we should never set `static` instance to `null`?

Comment: Yes, the static instance is never set to null, you only update the instance variable httpListener

Comment: Why its bad idea to nullify `static` singleton?

Comment: static object may be used in many places inside the project. When the static object is set to null, and other code use it, it can cause exception. It can causing race condition and make it harder to debug (finding the cause where the object set to null).

Comment: For instance, the following code will cause issues: `Listener l = Listener.Instance; l.DoSomething();` If the static instance is set to null between the calls, you could end up with a state you don't want, i.e. a "loose variable" since the variable l is stored in a local state outside the control of the Listener class.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that on failure the instance constructor is setting the static member listener to null. However, control then returns to the static constructor which sets the static member listener to the object that was created in the instance constructor. Hence, the behaviour you're seeing.

I'd argue that your (instance) constructor is trying to do too much. I would move the 'start listening' logic into a separate method and call that from anywhere other than the instance constructor. That will make your error handling a little easier e.g.

```
class Listener
{
    public static Listener listener = null;  //singleton instance

    //member variables
    private HttpListener httpListener = null;
    private int port = -1;

    static Listener GetListener()
    {
        if (listener != null)
        {
            return listener;
        }

        try
        {
            listener = new Listener();
            listener.StartListening();
            return listener;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //cant listen on randomly chosen port
            listener.Cleanup();
            listener = null;
            throw;
        }
    }

    private Listener()
    {
        port = RandomlyGenerate();
        httpListener = new HttpListener();
    }

    private void StartListening()
    {
        //start listening
    }

    private void Cleanup()
    {
        httpListener.Close();
        httpListener = null;
        port = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: So this must also contain something `static Listener getListener()` and I have to do `Listener.getListener().StartListening()` ?

Comment: Yup. I've replaced the static constructor with a static GetListener() which is better. The above code is illustrative e.g. it's not thread safe, GetListener() could try listening on more than one port until it finds one that works and it's probably not necessary to cleanup the HttpListener on every attempt.

Comment: But what about nullifying `listener`? Or why its bad idea to nullify `static` singleton?

Comment: Your main use case is something like Listener.GetListener().DoSomething. However, if GetListener() returns null, then you'll get a null reference exception when the system tries to call DoSomething(). This would entail checking the return value of GetListener() every time which is not the greatest of designs.

Comment: Ohkay I have thought this: have `void init()` which will create `httpListener` and `port` and then start listening. I will call `listener.init()` inside `static EwsListener()` that way I dont have to attach `listener.` everywhere, also will not need to explicitly call `init()`, also I will not set `listener = null`, so that `getListener()` will always return instance.